# How to change dropdown option selected with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

Jquery code

```
 $( function() {

        $( '#copy' ).click(function() {
            var enid = $("#enid").text(); 
            $('#copy').html('Loading...');
        $.ajax( {
                        url : 'http://localhost/crm/customers/copy_enquirer',
                        type : 'post',
                        data : "enid="+enid,
                        success : function( resp ) {
                                     $('#race').val($('#inner_3',resp).html());
                        }
            });
               return false;
        });
    });
```

my form

```
 <select name="race" id="race">
<option value="chinese">Chinese</option>
<option value="indian">Indian</option>
<option value="malay">Malay</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

if is   $('#race').val('malay');   the form will change to Malay when onclick, but if is       $('#race').val($('#inner_3',resp).html());   the dropdown list will not change after onclick. I have to use    $('#race').val($('#inner_3',resp).html());   since the value is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're doing:

```
$('#inner_3',resp).html();
```

What is actually happening in the background is:

```
$(resp).find('#inner_3').html();
```

If `#inner_3` is at the *top level* of the HTML that was returned, the [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method won't help you since it only looks at *descendants* of the top level elements.

You'll need to use [`filter()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead.

```
$('#race').val( $(resp).find('#inner_3').html() );
```

Also, keep in mind that you may need to use [`jQuery.trim()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to trim any whitespace from the HTML if there is any.

Comment: $('#race').val( $(resp).find('#inner_3').html() ); is not working. and i change the .find into .filter now look like $('#race').val( $(resp).filter('#inner_3').html() ); when onclick the dropdown menu it show nothing. i not sure where's the jquery.trim() should put. show me where's the mistake. i am only a beginner level on js.

Comment: @bravo: I am having to guess at the issue because you haven't provide the value of the `resp` that you're using. If you provide that, I could be more help. First, try  `$.trim( $(resp).find('#inner_3').html() )` (and the same with the `filter` version).

Comment: @bravo: You're welcome. Please remember to click the large checkmark to the left of this answer if it was helpful.